# SQL Server Database Table Normalization ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, database-normalization

I have an ASP.NET MVC application and by default I have an `AspNetUsers` table that stores users. I actually have two types of users on my site, stored inside the same table, with both of their distinctive columns! Obviously I realize this is not the way to go and I am trying to normalize it.

Here is the table definition so far:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUsers] 
(
    [Id]                   NVARCHAR (128)  NOT NULL,
    [Email]                NVARCHAR (256)  NOT NULL,
    [EmailConfirmed]       BIT             NOT NULL,
    [PasswordHash]         NVARCHAR (MAX)  NULL,
    [SecurityStamp]        NVARCHAR (MAX)  NULL,
    [PhoneNumber]          NVARCHAR (50)   NULL,
    [PhoneNumberConfirmed] BIT             NULL,
    [TwoFactorEnabled]     BIT             NOT NULL,
    [LockoutEndDateUtc]    DATETIME        NULL,
    [LockoutEnabled]       BIT             NOT NULL,
    [AccessFailedCount]    INT             NOT NULL,
    [FirstName]            NVARCHAR (50)   NULL,
    [LastName]             NVARCHAR (50)   NULL,
    [Role]                 NVARCHAR (50)   NOT NULL,
    [City]                 NVARCHAR (50)   NULL,
    [ZipCode]              NVARCHAR (50)   NULL,
    [Region]               NVARCHAR (50)   NULL,
    [Language]             NVARCHAR (50)   NULL,
    [University]           NVARCHAR (50)   NULL,
    [StudyProgramme]       NVARCHAR (50)   NULL,
    [Semester]             INT             NULL,
    [GraduationDate]       NVARCHAR (50)   NULL,
    [Description]          NVARCHAR (2000) NULL,
    [Skills]               NVARCHAR (2000) NULL,
    [Experience]           NVARCHAR (2000) NULL,
    [UserName]             NVARCHAR (50)   NOT NULL,
    [WorkField]            NVARCHAR (50)   NULL,
    [NrEmployees]          INT             NULL,
    [CompanyName]          NVARCHAR (50)   NULL,
    [Website]              NVARCHAR (50)   NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.AspNetUsers] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
GO

CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [UserNameIndex]
    ON [dbo].[AspNetUsers]([Email] ASC);
```

I want to store the Student/Company user specific fields in a separate tables, however I am not sure how to go about doing this:

Student specific:

```
    [FirstName]            NVARCHAR (50)   NULL,
    [LastName]             NVARCHAR (50)   NULL,
    [Language]             NVARCHAR (50)   NULL,
    [University]           NVARCHAR (50)   NULL,
    [StudyProgramme]       NVARCHAR (50)   NULL,
    [Semester]             INT             NULL,
    [GraduationDate]       NVARCHAR (50)   NULL,
    [Skills]               NVARCHAR (2000) NULL,
    [Experience]           NVARCHAR (2000) NULL,
```

Company specific:

```
[WorkField]            NVARCHAR (50)   NULL,
[NrEmployees]          INT             NULL,
[CompanyName]          NVARCHAR (50)   NULL,
[Website]              NVARCHAR (50)   NULL,
```

I am not sure how to go about the normalization process. Do I just modify `AspNetUsers` table and create two new tables? What kind of constraints do I add to them? How do I make the relationship between them?

Comment: Need a little more clarity here - What kind of relationship do you want User and Company/Student to have? Is user one to one with Student and Company or one to many? Can a User be tied to both a student and a company record?

Comment: I want a 1-to-1. Each User MUST be either Student or Company but not both.

Comment: I would create a cross reference table that stores the UserID, TypeId(Student/Company), and ReferenceID. Then make the cross reference table have a unique constraint on UserID. The down side with this setup is that you cannot have a foreign key reference between ReferenceID and the Student/Company table directly though. But it will give the assurances you want.

Comment: So I will have four tables: AspNetUsers, CrossReferenceUsers, StudentUsers, CompanyUsers. The AspNetUsers will have all the 'basic' fields that both Student and Company require. CrossReferenceUses will have UserID nvarchar (128) NOT NULL, UNIQUE ? then I am guessing the both StudentTable and CompanyTable will have a ReferenceID field that also has a UNIQUE constraint?

Comment: Store your users in the single table. Then, any Student or Company specific info should go in Student and Company tables, with User ID as a reference to the user table. If you wish, you can then add some constraints to ensure the desired 1 to 1 mapping and that you don't have a user in both sub tables.

Comment: @ManoDestra can you post an answer ? I am not sure how the user registration would work after executing those modifications. I was thinking of making the registration simpler (only base user info), then once you login you can fill in the rest of the student/company specific info?

Comment: It's going to be too broad to give you an answer to this. That's how I'd design the database given your requirements. It's up to you how you then implement the logic to modify/access that data.

Comment: Alright thank you for your comment

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you need to have **two new tables** - one for each kind of user - and make them reference the "base" `AspNetUsers` table via its primary key.

Something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Student] 
(
    [StudentId] INT IDENTITY(1,1)
        CONSTRAINT PK_Student PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
    [UserId] NVARCHAR(128) NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT FK_Student_AspNetUsers
           FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES dbo.AspNetUsers(Id),
    .... your other student-specific columns....
)
```

and basically the same for the `Company`:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Company] 
(
     [CompanyId] INT IDENTITY(1,1)
         CONSTRAINT PK_Company PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
     [UserId] NVARCHAR(128) NOT NULL
         CONSTRAINT FK_Company_AspNetUsers
            FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES dbo.AspNetUsers(Id),
     .... your other company-specific columns....
)
```

I would *strongly suggest* **NOT** to modify the existing `AspNetUsers` table! Just add "connected" tables with the additional info to it - but leave it *as is*!

Comment: Why should I not modify it? The whole point is that I should not store things like "Company Name" for the Student as NULL for no reason or "Graduation Date" for Company as NULL.

Comment: Well, first of all - it's a **system** table - so hands off! Secondly: if you squeeze all the additional properties for students and company into the base table, then you end up with a lot of potential `NULL` columns, and you cannot enforce any `NOT NULL` constraints on those new properties that *would make sense* in the student or company domain - since you need to accommodate both scenarios in a single set of columns, all those columns end up being NULLable

Comment: Yes...that is the problem now... everything is thrown into a single table and fields that makes sense for students are just stored as NULL in companies. I don't get the "system table" argument. I modified it lots of times without any problems. (adding/removing columns)

Comment: From 30+ years of experience: if something is developed and provided by a third party (like Microsoft in this case), **do not** modify it - when a next version comes around, suddenly you'll have to either do the modifications all over again (do you still know everything you've changed, 10 months or 2 years later??) and you have lots of potential trouble. If it's a system-/custom-provided solution - just **extend** it, don't modify it - trust me....

Comment: Alright fair point, but in my case I could easily modify Microsoft's default table to my liking, I thought that was the point, never thought of it like you put it. However for this case I think I will try deleting the columns that would be student/company specific and create new ones inside the new tables, what do you say? This way the original AspNetUsers table will be more close to the original

Comment: Sounds like a better plan than what you have now, for sure!

Answer (score 1):

You can't normalize yet because:
1. You have not specified a level of normalization.
1a. You have not specified calculated fields, if any. 
2. If you are going to 2NF you appear to have much redundant data in attributes such as region and university. 
3. If you are going to BCNF, you have not specified determinants.

A cursory look at your schema tells me you are not even in 1NF because you have an attribute "skills" that does not appear to be atomic, based soley on the name of it. I am guessing, of course.

Now I will step aside as I am voted down.

Comment: I will rethink everything and update my post by tomorrow, thank you for your answer

Comment: Hey! I got voted up! There is hope for me!   In all seriousness, you do need to take it one Normalization Level at a time, hopefully getting all the way to BCNF.

Comment: Yes, I think I will take some time to better understand Normalization and hopefully come up with either a better question or find the answer myself along the way.

Comment: Alright so I am pretty sure I need 1NF. Right now I have modified the standard AspNetUsers table to not have any Student/Company specific fields (GraduationDate/CompanyName etc). It's primary key is the Id, then the Student and Company tables have UserId which are foreign keys. AspNetUsers also has a Role field. When registering if you click I am a student or company your account gets Student/Company role (so I can use [Authorize]). However how do I go about adding a new entry to, say, the Student table when they register? Like they fill in the base fields, then they need the student specific?

Comment: part2: Basically I would need some kind of query to check if the User.Identity.GetUserId(); variable is the same for Id and UserId ForeignKey

Comment: do you have any idea @nicomp ?

Comment: Are you at BCNF yet? Then we can write the query.

Comment: I'm gonna attempt some inheritance hierarchies (Table per Hierarchy) will try to post an answer when I got somewhere

Comment: I have made another question, turns out I had some problems regarding he Code First Approach as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37345041/inheritance-code-first-table-per-hierarchy-to-existing-database-trying-to-add